# two different version of jquery cdn links on same page issue

Tags: jquery

i have two different jquery link on the page because of that my functionality is not working

```
  <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>

    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>

          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"> 
      </script>

           <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#box,#box1,#box2').draggable({
              stack: "div",
              distance: 0
            });

            });
            </script>
```

Comment: So remove one??  Actually you do not have two different versions.  You have the same version twice

Comment: Unless you have a script that uses jQuery between the two jQuery links, it shouldn't cause a problem. The problem happens when the copy of jQuery changes after a script that uses it is run.

Comment: If you really need to have multiple copies of jQuery, you need to use `jQuery.noConflict()`.

Comment: how to resolve the problem ?

Comment: Again, not two versions.  The first two are the same version of jQuery.  The third one is an inclusion of jquery ui, which is not the same thing.  One of the `jquery.min.js` should be removed as doing it twice here is pointless.  Other than that, if you still have issues, the question needs to be clarified as to what those issues are.

Comment: you can find my source code as well as issue https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54593195/revisions

Answer (score 0):

I think you use something like a cms or other application which render your page.
So there are 2 bundles/modules etc. which inlcudes same jquery.

In this case is not a jquery question - problem should be in your server-side application.